# How to Split Screen & Auto-size Programs on Vertical Monitor

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, autohotkey

My monitor is one a vertical orientation, so snapping windows to top and bottom is impossible.

I am using Windows 10.

I need help finding a way to:

1. Auto start Google Chrome and Internet Explorer.
2. Resize and snap Google Chrome to the top half of the screen.

   Resize and snap Internet Explorer to the bottom half of the screen.
3. I need Google Chrome and Internet Explorer to start up on boot and have it resized and snapped to the top and bottom of the monitor vertically.

I am having trouble doing this via scripts and AutoHotKey. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the scripts that you tried using?

Answer (score 0):

Using AHK, you could try moving the window to a position defined as a percentage of the original:

```
ifwinexist, ahk_class IEFrame
{
    Winactivate
    send #{up} ;ensures correct resize.
    sleep 200 ;waits 0.2 Secs for resize to occur.
    y := (A_ScreenHeight*0.5) ;simply half the screen height.
    WinMove,,%y% ;move the window to position defined in line above.
}
Return
```